# In Arkham Horror, where do flying monsters in location areas go when no investigator is near?

Tags: arkham-horror

The rulebook says

> If the flying monster is in a street area with no investigators and there are no investigators in a connected street area, it moves to the Sky.

Does this imply if it is in a location area with no investigators in sight, such as when a gate opens, it goes to the sky? Is there a supporting reference for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flying monsters can be in one of three places when the action to move them may occur:

- Location
- Streets
- Sky

If it is in a location or the streets, the monster moves to a **connected** street location if there is an investigator there. If there is no investigator, it goes to the sky

If it is in the sky, it moves to **any** street location which contains an investigator. If there are no investigators in any street locations, it does not move. When there are multiple investigators, it goes to the investigator with the lowest current sneak value. If there is still a tie, the first player decides where it goes.

The below is a quote from version 1.7 of the FAQ. The latest version (2.0) can be found [here](https://images-cdn.fantasyflightgames.com/filer_public/9b/2a/9b2a9f8f-0b42-45ba-bcd2-87dc55c68f5f/complete_arkham_horror_faq.pdf) (it's approx. 25mb PDF.):

> 1. Flying monsters only move when their symbol comes up in the Mythos Phase, just like other monsters.
> 2. Flying monsters will not leave a space that already contains an investigator.
> 3. When a flying monster in a street area or location moves, it will either move to an adjacent street space that has an investigator in
>      it, or failing that, move to the Sky.
> 4. When a flying monster in the Sky moves, it will move to any street space on the board with an investigator in it. If there’s more than
>      one investigator to choose from, the monster moves into the space of
>      the investigator with the lowest Sneak value. If the investigators’
>      Sneak values are the same, the first player chooses which investigator
>      the monster moves toward, as usual. If there are no investigators in a
>      street space, the monster remains in the Sky.